# Seperate results based on type Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch and am struggling with a concept that I hope someone would be kind enough to point me in the right direction.  I have a query that returns results of a type Document.  This works fine.  I want to also have a seperate set of results for objects of type Event.  How can I accomplish this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the query that works:

```
"query": {  

    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { "match": { 
            "sortableTitle":  {
              "query": query,
              "boost": 3,
              "operator": "and"
        }}},
        { "match": { 
            "content":  {
              "query": query,
              "boost": 2,
              "operator": "or"
        }}},
        { "match": { 
            "description":  {
              "query": query,
              "boost": 1,
              "operator": "or"
        }}},
      ],
        "must": {
            "match": {
            "metaType":{
                "query": "Document",
                "operator": "and"
        }}},

    },//end bool

},//end query
```

Comment: Do you want to get them back in the same response or two different responses? How do you connect to elasticsearch? Are you using some client library or you are interested in curl-based solution?

Comment: Hello.  I am using angularjs to connect.  Again, I'm really new to this and my head is spinning slightly trying to understand some concepts.  Thank you for your prompt response.ds

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the type of the documents that you want to get back with your request. The way you specify the type depends on the client that you are using, and it's not part of the request. In case of elasticsearch.js the parameter that you are looking for is called `type` and it should appear on the same level as `body` where your request goes:

```
client.search({
  index: 'myindex',
  type: 'Document',
  body: {
    query: {
```

Comment: Ok.  So my confusion is in that the built in _type field in ES currently is all of type document.  I have another field that was indexed as "metaType".   Also, are you saying that I need to run two seperate queries with the type parameter set to the different values to get back the seperate results?  Sorry for all of the questions, i'm learning by "breaking" and asking.

Comment: You need to run 2 separate queries or run two queries combined into msearch.